# Matching dataframes by id fails for some values

Tags: r

I have a very large dataset with a few thousand missing values, which looks something like the below:

```
df1:
                            doi journal year
1  10.1037/0002-9432.76.1.13    <NA>   NA
2  10.1037/0002-9432.76.1.13    <NA>   NA
3  10.1037/0002-9432.76.1.13    <NA>   NA
4 10.1037/0003-066X.60.8.750    <NA>   NA
5 10.1037/0003-066X.60.8.750    <NA>   NA
6 10.1037/0003-066X.60.8.750    <NA>   NA
```

I have another dataframe which contains all missing journal names and years:

```
df2:
                          doi year                             journal
17  10.1037/0002-9432.76.1.13 2006 American Journal of Orthopsychiatry
18  10.1037/0002-9432.76.1.13 2006 American Journal of Orthopsychiatry
19  10.1037/0002-9432.76.1.13 2006 American Journal of Orthopsychiatry
31 10.1037/0003-066x.60.8.750 2005               American Psychologist
32 10.1037/0003-066x.60.8.750 2005               American Psychologist
33 10.1037/0003-066x.60.8.750 2005               American Psychologist
```

Yet when I try to match the two by their doi value

```
df1$year[is.na(df1$year)] <- df2$year[match(df1$doi[is.na(df1$year)], df2$doi)]
df1$journal[is.na(df1$journal)] <- df2$journal[match(df1$doi[is.na(df1$journal)], df2$doi)]
```

this only works for some:

```
Result:
                             doi                             journal year
1  10.1037/0002-9432.76.1.13 American Journal of Orthopsychiatry 2006
2  10.1037/0002-9432.76.1.13 American Journal of Orthopsychiatry 2006
3  10.1037/0002-9432.76.1.13 American Journal of Orthopsychiatry 2006
4 10.1037/0003-066X.60.8.750                                <NA>   NA
5 10.1037/0003-066X.60.8.750                                <NA>   NA
6 10.1037/0003-066X.60.8.750                                <NA>   NA
```

I have tried different ways of matching the dataframes (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593881/replace-na-values-in-dataframe-variable-with-values-from-other-dataframe-by-id) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847299/using-ifelse-to-replace-nas-in-one-data-frame-by-referencing-another-data-fram)), as well as trimming the white-space when loading the dataframes, but no success. "doi" and "journal" are character vectors, and "year" is an integer. Very thankful if anyone has some insight.

Comment: R is case sensitive so your problem is within the way the doi is displayed in the values the produce the NA's you have a capital X in your doi in one df but not in the other

Comment: Ading to @Sarina's comment: Using `tolower` like this `match(df1$doi[is.na(df1$year)], tolower(df2$doi))` could solve the problem.

Comment: and you may still need  `trimws`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much obliged @Sarina and @Jaap, your comments were correct and `tolower`solved the issue for me.

> R is case sensitive so your problem is within the way the doi is displayed in the values the produce the NA's you have a capital X in your doi in one df but not in the other – Sarina
>
> Ading to @Sarina's comment: Using tolower like this match(df1$doi[is.na(df1$year)], tolower(df2$doi)) could solve the problem. – Jaap

Answer (score 1):

The OP mentioned that he has *a very large dataset with a few thousand missing values*.

This is why I felt challenged to suggest a `data.table` solution using *update on join* instead of base R `match()` although the actual problem has been solved already by using `tolower()`.

```
library(data.table)

#prepare doi
setDT(df1)[, doi := tolower(doi)]
setDT(df2)[, doi := tolower(doi)]

#join
df1[unique(df2), on = "doi", `:=`(year = i.year, journal = i.journal)]

df1
#                          doi                             journal year
#1:  10.1037/0002-9432.76.1.13 American Journal of Orthopsychiatry 2006
#2:  10.1037/0002-9432.76.1.13 American Journal of Orthopsychiatry 2006
#3:  10.1037/0002-9432.76.1.13 American Journal of Orthopsychiatry 2006
#4: 10.1037/0003-066X.60.8.750               American Psychologist 2005
#5: 10.1037/0003-066X.60.8.750               American Psychologist 2005
#6: 10.1037/0003-066X.60.8.750               American Psychologist 2005
```

Note that this will replace *all* values of `year` and `journal` in `df1` by the values given in `df2` for matching `doi` irrespective if they are `NA` or not.

There is a variant which does only replace values if they are `NA`:

```
df1[unique(df2), on = "doi", 
    `:=`(year = replace(year, is.na(year), i.year), 
         journal = replace(journal, is.na(journal), i.journal))]
```

#### Benchmark

For a speed comparison between the three methods, `df1` has been appended to itself so that it has about 100'000 rows. As `df1` is updated in itself, each benchmark run has to start with a fresh copy. The copy operation is included in the benchmark as well.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  copy = df1 <- copy(df1_orig),
  OP_match = {
    df1 <- copy(df1_orig)
    df1$year[is.na(df1$year)] <- df2$year[match(df1$doi[is.na(df1$year)], df2$doi)]
    df1$journal[is.na(df1$journal)] <- df2$journal[match(df1$doi[is.na(df1$journal)], df2$doi)]
  },
  update_on_join = {
    df1 <- copy(df1_orig)
    df1[unique(df2), on = "doi", `:=`(year = i.year, journal = i.journal)]
  },
  replace_on_join = {
    df1 <- copy(df1_orig)
    df1[unique(df2), on = "doi", 
        `:=`(year = replace(year, is.na(year), i.year), 
             journal = replace(journal, is.na(journal), i.journal))]
  },
  times = 100L
)
```

The results show that _update_on_join_ is nearly three times faster than base R using `match()` for this case:

```
Unit: microseconds
            expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval
            copy   760.449   978.691  1129.290  1071.388  1202.974   2085.383   100
        OP_match 12376.362 14532.352 16215.333 15295.821 17497.497  35352.941   100
  update_on_join  5101.879  5585.939  6136.479  5914.435  6416.240   9272.643   100
 replace_on_join  7998.306  8729.303 11822.586  9367.416  9802.767 227385.521   100
```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- fread(
  "rn                    doi journal year
1  10.1037/0002-9432.76.1.13    <NA>   NA
2  10.1037/0002-9432.76.1.13    <NA>   NA
3  10.1037/0002-9432.76.1.13    <NA>   NA
4  10.1037/0003-066X.60.8.750   <NA>   NA
5  10.1037/0003-066X.60.8.750   <NA>   NA
6  10.1037/0003-066X.60.8.750   <NA>   NA",
  drop = 1, na.strings = c("NA", "<NA>"))
df1[, journal := as.character(journal)]
df1[, year := as.integer(year)]

df2 <- fread(
  "rn,                       doi, year,                             journal
  17,  10.1037/0002-9432.76.1.13, 2006, American Journal of Orthopsychiatry
  18,  10.1037/0002-9432.76.1.13, 2006, American Journal of Orthopsychiatry
  19,  10.1037/0002-9432.76.1.13, 2006, American Journal of Orthopsychiatry
  31, 10.1037/0003-066x.60.8.750, 2005,               American Psychologist
  32, 10.1037/0003-066x.60.8.750, 2005,               American Psychologist
  33, 10.1037/0003-066x.60.8.750, 2005,               American Psychologist",
  drop = 1)

#prepare doi
df1[, doi := tolower(doi)]
df2[, doi := tolower(doi)]

#create benchmark data

df1_orig <- copy(df1)
df2_orig <- copy(df2)

for (i in seq_len(14L)) df1_orig <- rbind(df1_orig, df1_orig)
nrow(df1_orig)
```